# How can I validate XML with Firefox?

Tags: xml, firefox, xsd, dtd, validation

Firefox does not read an external DTD and it does not provide schema evaluation even when an external schema definition is included in the XML file.

If I want to validate the XML against a DTD or an XSD at the Firefox browser directly or by using JavaScript, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

[This add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2897) is made for firefox version < 2.X

But why firefox after all .. If you need, then there are some free xml editors as well ..

Comment: Basically I have an XHTML page, which has new tags apart from the usual ones, and JavaScript that evaluates these new tags. Thus, the JavaScript in the code should be able to manipulate the XHTML.

Comment: However, before evaluating the new tags, the JavaScript must validate the XHTML or the browser should automatically validate the XHTML against a new DTD (that has the new tags definitions). Firefox, or other browsers for that matter, seem to override and not read any external DTD specification that I give.

If we visualize this new XHTML with new tags, as just another XML , whose schema is like that of XHTML, then we could try to validate the XML against a external XSD. However that doesn't seem possible either.

Comment: Any suggestions for validation in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is the only browser that supports DTD/XSD validation out of the box.

It looks like you're building a [web based xml editor](http://www.google.com/search?q=web+based+xml+editor). Why not use an off the self product?